# icann and new gTLD domains

Tags: domain, domain-name, domain-registration

Does anyone knows when will be these new `domains extensions` available?

I would like to register now a `TLD` , but when it will be available for my web site?

Is here any approximative date?

Also is there any list of ALREADY available tld?

Comment: The become available, when they become available.  Each tld is separate.

Comment: You should contact the applicant/registrant of the specific TLD and ask them.

Comment: See: https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/

Comment: gandi.net have a good list of most currently avalible one but there are some restrictions. For example, .ru isn't registerable by Russian general public. What was the TLD you are looking for?

Comment: @tombull89 Well, he says he is interested in the NEW TLD's. YOu know, those that are now being in the approoval process. Sending him to a list of current stuff OBVIOUSLY won't help him.

Comment: @TomTom, I don't think much will help at this point, given the OP's other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the official list of available TLDs at http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt.

Note that many have restrictions - as an example, .MO requires you to have a company registered in Macau.

The new gTLDs will be added here once they're approved, but that's on a per-TLD basis and I'd expect most of them to be tied up in debate for quite some time.

Answer (score 1):

I afraid that you'll have to look to ICANN for such information (http://www.icann.org).

Comment: i edited question pls take a look